# I cannot find the SQLite Instance on Haskell / Snap based server

Tags: ubuntu, sqlite

I have inherited a Haskell based server (on Ubuntu) on which SQLite is being used for authentication through the Snap SQLite-Auth module.

After searching the server I am unable to locate the SQLite "instance" (I know it really isn't an instance). I know it is there because I can see the database that was created and the calls from the snaplet are executed when users authenticate. I type SQLite or SQLite3 into the terminal and I get the error:

> The program 'sqlite3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:...

Typing `locate sqlite` into the terminal shows me everything *but* the executable that needs to be run for SQLite.

I want to be able to make use of SQLite on the server for some other data operations.

Do I need to install another instance of SQLite? Or can one of you who is much more knowledgeable about this point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, only the SQLite libraries are installed, possibly together with your application, or separately, eg. with the package `libsqlite0` or `libsqlite3`. You can install the CLI program with `apt-get install sqlite` (or `sqlite3`).

You can get a list of `sqlite` related installed packages with

```
 dpkg --get-selections | grep sqlite
```

Comment: I was able to find those files immediately and I am now on to installing the CLI program. I just assumed that it would be there. :-/